# Filtering rows within two standard deviation or beyond in r

Tags: r, dplyr, standard-deviation

My idea is to filter my rows within the first two standard deviation or beyond if there exist values.

So this is my dummy dataset

```
nr1 = 4; nr2 = 8; nr3 = 6; nr = nr1 + nr2 + nr3
nc1 = 6; nc2 = 8; nc3 = 10; nc = nc1 + nc2 + nc3
mat = cbind(rbind(matrix(rnorm(nr1*nc1, mean = 1,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr1),
          matrix(rnorm(nr2*nc1, mean = 0,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr2),
          matrix(rnorm(nr3*nc1, mean = 0,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr3)),
    rbind(matrix(rnorm(nr1*nc2, mean = 0,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr1),
          matrix(rnorm(nr2*nc2, mean = 1,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr2),
          matrix(rnorm(nr3*nc2, mean = 0,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr3)),
    rbind(matrix(rnorm(nr1*nc3, mean = 0.5, sd = 0.5), nr = nr1),
          matrix(rnorm(nr2*nc3, mean = 0.5, sd = 0.5), nr = nr2),
          matrix(rnorm(nr3*nc3, mean = 1,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr3))
   )
mat = mat[sample(nr, nr), sample(nc, nc)] # random shuffle rows and columns
rownames(mat) = paste0("row", seq_len(nr))
colnames(mat) = paste0("column", seq_len(nc))
```

In order to calculate the row-wise std deviation I used this

```
rld2 <- as.data.frame((m)) %>% rownames_to_column('gene')


bb <- rld2 %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  do(data.frame(., rsds = sd(unlist(.[2:length(.)]))))
```

Now my idea is to filter out row which are within [image: std dev] The first, second and the third std deviation.

How do i Implement that?

Any help or suggestion would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to transpose the data frame and create a longer table. Then the filtering operations become fairly easy, see below:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- t(mat) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "gene") %>% 
  group_by(gene) %>% 
  mutate(meanval = mean(value), stdev = sd(value))
```

Now you can filter easily:

```r
  df %>% 
   filter(abs((value-meanval)/stdev)>2)
```

or make different groups:

```r
  df %>% 
   mutate(
    fact = abs((value-meanval)/stdev),
    stgroup = case_when(
      fact < 1 ~ "<1",
      fact <=2 ~ "1-2",
      fact >2  ~ ">2",
      TRUE     ~ NA_character_
      )
    )
```

Comment: let me run this